# Не работает функция запроса номера телефона aiogram, когда пользователь использует телефон, на пк работает

Tags: python, aiogram

**keyboard.py**

```
    def contact_keyboard(self):
        markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        first_button = KeyboardButton(text=(" Отправить"), request_contact=True)
        markup.add(first_button)
        return markup
```

**handler.py**

```
@dp.message_handler(Command('start'))
async def on_start_test(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer('Привет, ' + str(message.from_user.full_name) + '\nНужно подтвердить номер', reply_markup= markup)
    await CallbackOnStart.Q1.set()


@dp.message_handler(content_types=types.ContentType.CONTACT, state = CallbackOnStart.Q1)
async def tower(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    contact = message.contact
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте следующий код:

## keyboard.py

```
def contact_keyboard():
    markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    first_button = KeyboardButton(text=(" Отправить"), request_contact=True)
    markup.add(first_button)
    return markup
```

## handler.py

```
@dp.message_handler(Command('start'))
async def on_start_test(message: types.Message):
    markup = contact_keyboard()
    await message.answer('Привет, ' + str(message.from_user.full_name) + '\nНужно подтвердить номер', reply_markup=markup)
    await CallbackOnStart.Q1.set()


@dp.message_handler(content_types=types.ContentType.CONTACT, state=CallbackOnStart.Q1)
async def tower(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    try:
        contact = message.contact.phone_number
        await message.answer(f"Спасибо за отправку номера телефона: {contact}")
    except Exception as e:
        await message.answer(f"Произошла ошибка: {e}")
```